# Emploi du futur antérieur

Tags: temps-grammatical, futur

> En étudiant la première unité, tu as rencontré des noms précédés de l'article défini. Tu auras distingué trois articles : der, das et die.

Cet extrait est tiré d'un manuel d'allemand du collège (6<sup>e</sup>). Je ne comprends pas l'usage du futur antérieur dans ce contexte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il est employé ici pour signifier une progression dans le temps.

"En étudiant la première unité" est le point de départ (disons avant-hier) et le futur de cet événement est "la distinction des 3 articles" (disons hier). Cet ėvénement futur, par rapport au contexte initial, est aujourd'hui, à la lecture de ces lignes, bel et bien terminé, d'où la possibilité d'employer un futur antėrieur.

Un passé composé aurait pu convenir, mais ce futur antérieur est je trouve bien plus élégant car on utilise déjà un passé composé peu avant et il établit de plus clairement la chronologie sans devoir employer un adverbe supplémentaire.